# Handling IIS hosted web service startup failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis, error-handling

I have a web service (ASP.NET) which tries to connect to a Database in Application_OnStart method. However, due to some reason if I cant connect to DB, I want to throw an exception and stop the initialization so that IIS can restart it again. But what I observe is that app pool is started even if the exception is thrown from Application_OnStart method. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: if you cannot connect to the DB, so you just start up again, what do you expect to happen that is different to the first time? Is it that you really are looking for a way to handle 'not being able to connect' in a graceful way?

Comment: @mikelegg The DB connectivity issue is generally short lived. If I retry after 5 min, it will work. I can do sleep wait in code, but I thought it would be better to do via IIS.

Comment: In my opinion, you have to write the code for it there is no way by using iis. you could try some settings for the application pool like set start mode to “on demand” and Set Idle Time-Out (minutes) to 1 or based on your requirement.